# CardView background is not changing when onViewStateRestored is fired

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I have a BottomSheetFragment that contains 5 cardView and a bunch of other elements.

The Card view act as a RadioButton, so when I click it, its background changes to black and the text color changes to white, but when I dismiss the BottomSheetFragment it goes back to default and none of the cards are selected.

When I dismiss my BottomSheet and show it again, I want my last CardView selected to be selected again.

```
package com.hasnaoui.e_commerceoil

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_bottom_sheet.*
import java.io.Serializable
import kotlin.math.log

class BottomSheetFragment:BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private var previousSelect:Int?=null
    private var newFilterValue:String?=null
    private var previousSelectPrice:Int?=null
    private var previousSelectRating:String?=null
    private var b:CardView?=null
    private var id: String? = null
    private var btn:Button? = null
    private var cardView:CardView? = null

    var listOfProductFiltered = ArrayList<Product>()
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_bottom_sheet, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("onViewCreated","onViewCreated called")
        
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        radioGroup1.clearCheck() // this is so we can start fresh, with no selection on both RadioGroups
        radioGroup2.clearCheck()
        radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener1)
        radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener2)
        radioGroup3!!.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener3)
        card1?.setOnClickListener(listener)
        card2?.setOnClickListener(listener)
        card3?.setOnClickListener(listener)
        card4?.setOnClickListener(listener)
        card5?.setOnClickListener(listener)


        apply!!.setOnClickListener {
            val mainActivity = MainActivity.instance
            if (previousSelect != null){
                id = resources.getResourceEntryName(previousSelect!!)
                btn = view.findViewById(resources.getIdentifier(id, "id", context?.packageName)) as Button
                if(newFilterValue != btn!!.text.toString()){
                    for(product in  mainActivity.listOfProduct){
                        for (tag in product.tags!!){
                            if (tag == btn!!.text.toString()){
                                listOfProductFiltered.add(product)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    newFilterValue =  btn!!.text.toString()
                }
            }
            if (previousSelectRating!=null){
                if (listOfProductFiltered.size>0){
                    filterByRating(listOfProductFiltered)
                    }
                else{
                    listOfProductFiltered =  mainActivity.listOfProduct
                    filterByRating(listOfProductFiltered)
                }

            }


            if(listOfProductFiltered.size>0){
                mainActivity.createMyRecycle(listOfProductFiltered)
            }

            this.dismiss()

        }

        dismiss.setOnClickListener{
            val chkId1: Int = radioGroup1.checkedRadioButtonId
            val chkId2: Int = radioGroup2.checkedRadioButtonId
            val chkId3: Int = rating.checkedRadioButtonId
            val realCheck = if (chkId1 == -1) chkId2 else chkId1
            this.dismiss()
            Log.e("XXX2", "$realCheck")
            Log.e("chkId3", "$chkId3")

                   }
        
    }




    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("onViewStateRestored","onViewStateRestored called")
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
            if (b != null){
            b!!.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
            val linearLayout = b!!.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
            val constrainLinearLayout = linearLayout.getChildAt(0) as 
            ConstraintLayout
            val textView = constrainLinearLayout.getChildAt(0) as TextView
            Log.e("textView",textView.text.toString())
            println(textView)
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            reset(b!!.resources.getResourceEntryName(b!!.id))
        }


    }

    private val listener1: RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener =
        RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
            if (previousSelect !=null){
                changeTextColor(previousSelect!!, "Black")
            }

            if (checkedId != -1) {
                radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null) // remove the listener before clearing so we don't throw that stackoverflow exception(like Vladimir Volodin pointed out)
                radioGroup2.clearCheck() // clear the second RadioGroup!
                radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener2) //reset the listener
                Log.e("XXX2", "$checkedId")
            }

            changeTextColor(checkedId, "White")
            previousSelect = checkedId
        }

    private val listener2: RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener =
        RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
            if (previousSelect !=null){
                changeTextColor(previousSelect!!, "Black")
            }
            if (checkedId != -1) {
                radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
                radioGroup1.clearCheck()
                radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener1)
                Log.e("XXX2", "$checkedId")
            }
            changeTextColor(checkedId, "White")
            previousSelect = checkedId
        }

    private val listener3: RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener =
        RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
            if (previousSelectPrice !=null){
                changeTextColor(previousSelectPrice!!, "Black")
            }

            changeTextColor(checkedId, "White")
            previousSelectPrice = checkedId
        }

    private val listener = View.OnClickListener { v->

        b = v as CardView
        b!!.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
        val linearLayout = b!!.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
        val constrainLinearLayout = linearLayout.getChildAt(0) as ConstraintLayout
        val textView = constrainLinearLayout.getChildAt(0) as TextView
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        previousSelectRating = textView.text.toString()
        Log.e("b listner",b!!.id.toString())
        reset(b!!.resources.getResourceEntryName(b!!.id))
    }

    private  fun reset(id: String){
        val cardList = listOf("card5", "card4", "card3", "card2", "card1")
        for (card in cardList){
            if(id != card){
                cardView = view?.findViewById(
                    resources.getIdentifier(
                        card,
                        "id",
                        context?.packageName
                    )
                ) as CardView
                cardView!!.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                val linearLayout = cardView!!.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
                val constrainLinearLayout = linearLayout.getChildAt(0) as ConstraintLayout
                val textView = constrainLinearLayout.getChildAt(0) as TextView
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)

            }
        }
    }


    private fun changeTextColor(idRadio: Int, color: String){
            id = resources.getResourceEntryName(idRadio)
            btn = view?.findViewById(resources.getIdentifier(id, "id", context?.packageName)) as Button
            if(color=="Black"){
                btn!!.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            }else{
                btn!!.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            }
    }

    private fun filterByRating(myList: ArrayList<Product>){
        Log.e("my list size",myList.size.toString())
        val itr: MutableIterator<Product> = myList.iterator()
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            val loan = itr.next()
            var sum = 0
            var keyValProd = 0.0
            loan.reviews!!.forEach { (key, value) ->
                run {
                    sum += value
                    keyValProd += key * value
                }
            }
            if (sum <=0 ) sum+=1
            val numberOfStars = keyValProd/sum
            Log.e("rating",numberOfStars.toString())
            if (numberOfStars<previousSelectRating!!.toDouble()){
                itr.remove()
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You have to save the selected card state someway, like store it in a `sharedpreferences` or you can send the selected card id back to the component you show the bottomSheet and keep the state there and send it back again while showing bottomsheet through the constructor. I prefer the first way.

Comment: But as you can see the variable b is a CardView and when i select a one card and I dismiss the bottomsheet and call it again and Log the id of b is the same as before the dismiss of the bottomsheet